# Warnings and Errors while installing Sql Server 2005 on 64 bit windows 7 machine

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to install **Sql Server 2005**.

Below are my machine configuration

- Windows 7 Home Basic - Operating System
- 4.00 GB - Ram
- 64 bit Operating System

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 successfully on it, but when I try  to install my Sql Server 2005, I get some warnings and errors as shown below while installation..

Firstly on double clicking the setup file, I get this message

[image]

I selected the Run Program option and continued with the setup...

and then later on I get this error

[image]

Below are detailed log for this warning/errors

**- IIS Feature Requirement (Warning)**
Messages
IIS Feature Requirement

Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) is either not installed or is disabled. IIS is required by some SQL Server features.  Without IIS, some SQL Server features will not be available for installation. To install all SQL Server features, install IIS from Add or Remove Programs in Control Panel or enable the IIS service through the Control Panel if it is already installed, and then run SQL Server Setup again. For a list of features that depend on IIS, see Features Supported by Editions of SQL Server in Books Online

**- ASP.Net Version Registration Requirement (Warning)**
Messages
ASP.Net Version Registration Requirement

64-bit ASP.Net is Registered. Required 32-bit ASP.Net to install Microsoft Reporting Services 2005(32-bit).

Please can anyone help me understand, how to get rid of these errors and help me install Sql Server 2005 on my machine

Comment: pls help me out on this people...

Comment: moved on to windows 8 on the same laptop, but the same problem persists

Comment: Are you running the setup as a Administrator? If not then please do so.

Comment: yes @TravisG i am running the setup as Administrator

Comment: and just to confirm you are using a 64bit setup of SQL server 2005 and not a 32bit one?

Comment: Did any of the below answers resolve your issue? If so please could you mark their solution as selected answer so they get credit & future visitors can benefit?  Thanks in advance.  FYI: @Raymund's resolved this for me.

Answer (score 11):

Like what your error said you need to install those.

For the IIS Feature Requirement you need to go to your Programs and Features and install them.
Here is a screenshot

[image]

You need to install the necessary components by ticking the checkboxes, this can be found on the requirements document of SQL Installation or have a look here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920201

Once IIS is installed you can resolve your second issue by going to Start -> Run and then type inetmgr.exe

In there enable the 32 bit applications by setting Application Pool Defaults.  Screen shot below

[image]

Comment: running server2013-x64 and enabling 32bit apps helped to pass that installation prerequisites test

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution. This helped me solve my problem.

[SQL2005 64bit install warning about ASP.Net Version Registration Requirement](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/d4cd0160-99b4-4923-b4c2-8870413d5390/)

[How to install SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services on a Windows Vista-based compute](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934164)

Answer (score 2):

Per your comments, you now have Windows 8 installed.  It looks like SQL Server 2005 is not supported on Windows 8.  See this SQL Server MSDN Blog entry [Installing SQL Server on Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/09/01/installing-sql-server-on-windows-8.aspx).

Now given that, it appears in this post that [some Stack Overflow users have installed SQL 2005 on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520551/how-to-install-sql-server-2005-express-in-windows-8).

Comment: Here's what I did to make SQL Server 2005 work on my Windows 8 Pro machine. I installed Windows 7 Pro, installed SQL Server 2005 and SS2K5 SP4 then installed the Windows 8 Pro upgrade. You can also install VS2005 (if you need it). Just install it before you install your Windows 8 upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue on Windows Server 2008 x64 and ended up here looking for a solution. I had enabled the IIS componenets and set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to true on all of the app pools. I still got the ASP .Net Warning when trying to install SQL 2005. Eventually I found that going into "Set Application Pool Defaults" and enabling the 32-bit apps there I successfully eradicated the warning.