# I tried to install SQL Server 2005 Express SP3 x64 on Windows 8 but the installer gives me an error

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-8

1. During setup I recieved this error:

The SQL Server service failed to start. For more information, see the SQL Server Books Online topics, "How to: View SQL Server 2005 Setup Log Files" and "Starting SQL Server Manually."

I read:   “Don't click cancel yet. From an installation of SQL Server 2005 SP3 or SP4 copy SQLSERVR.EXE and SQLOS.DLL files and put them in your SQL install folder and then click RETRY.

How do I find these files?

I’m only a user and don’t know much on computers programms, but need SQL Server working to run a taxes programme installation.

How can I solve the problema in a simple process?

Comment: As the instructions tell you, copy then from an existing installation of SQL Server 2005 SP3 or SP4; you have to have an already working installation somewhere. If you need help on your tax program installation, you should contact the program author or vendor for installation support. Good luck.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520551/how-to-install-sql-server-2005-express-in-windows-8

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2012/03/02/sql-server-express-and-windows-8.aspx) *SQL Server 2005 Express will not be suported on Windows 8*