# Installing SQL Server 2005 on Windows 8

Tags: sql-server, windows-8

How to install SQL Server 2005 on Windows 8 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

Perform these [steps](http://www.eulogika.net/index.php/install-sql-2005-developer-on-windows-8/?lang=en):-

> 1. Extract sqlncli.msi / sqlncli_x64.msi from SP3 or SP4. I did it from SP4
> 2. Install sqlncli
> 3. Start SQL Server 2005 Setup
> 4. During setup I recieved an error The SQL Server service failed to start. For more information, see the SQL Server Books Online topics,
>      “How to: View SQL Server 2005 Setup Log Files” and “Starting SQL
>      Server Manually.”
> 5. Don’t click cancel yet. From an installation of SQL Server 2005 SP3 or SP4 copy SQLSERVR.EXE and SQLOS.DLL files and put them in your SQL
>      install folder.
> 6. Click RETRY

From the reference [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520551/how-to-install-sql-server-2005-express-in-windows-8):-

> Microsoft says the SQL Server 2005 it's not compatible with Windows 8,
>   but I've run it without problems (only using SP3) except the
>   installation.
>
> After you run the install file SQLExpr.exe look for a hidden folder
>   recently created in the C drive. Copy the contents to another folder
>   and cancel the installer (or use WinRar to open the file and extract
>   the contents to a temp folder)
>
> After that, find the file sqlncli_x64.msi in the setup folder, and run
>   it.
>
> Now you are ready the run the setup.exe file and install SQL server
>   2005 without errors

[image]

Answer (score -2):

[See](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/09/01/installing-sql-server-on-windows-8.aspx)

SQL Server 2005 is NOT supported in Windows 8.  You need to change the server version or the operating system.

Comment: There is a workaround for this. Check my answer and the related Thread. People are using SQL Server 2005 in Windows8

Comment: Not supported doesn't mean not possible.  I have sql 2005 running on three Win8 pcs.