# MSSQL Server 2005 not installing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2005 but it is not working. When I used Management Studio, there is no server name present (when, as we all know, it has a default server name, right?). I am using Windows 8 and my unit has Visual Basic 6.0 installed on it. I am getting this error:

```
Error: 15507, Severity: 16, State: 1.
A key required by this operation appears to be corrupted.
```

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error? Thanks.

Comment: [VB 6.0 released 1998](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic), SQL Server 2005 is on [Extended Support](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/support/support-updates.aspx) and you have a new OS. I don't envy you your job in the slightest.

Comment: Snarkiness aside, what happened when you installed? When you look at your services, do you have SQL Server installed? If you run the SQL Server Manager, what do you have listed? If you try and connect to 'localhost' or '.' or '(local)' what error is reported?

Comment: A basic search on the text `a key required by this operation appears to be corrupted` and `15507` if you *really* to narrow things down lead to a host of articles discussing restores with [Transparent Data Encryption](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2463682). Is there some additional information that *might* be pertinent to the problem you're experiencing that we should know about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install SQL Server 2005 Express in Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520551/how-to-install-sql-server-2005-express-in-windows-8)

Comment: Here is a (posible) solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13732374/159270

Comment: Thanks @Aristos that is indeed a solution. I've flagged this question as a duplicate of that link you gave.